# How to fully customise LayerControl() in Folium?

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping, mapping, folium

I currently have a Folium map with this LayerControl component. Would it be possible to fully customise the layer control panel? For example, I would like it to not show the map style button saying "cartodbdark_matter", and I would like it to be transparent. Can I achieve this with Folium? If not, what tool should I be using?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible via combination of three informations

- All layers inherit from class `Layer` https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/folium/map.py#L30 and one of the option states the following

> control : bool, default True
> Whether the Layer will be included in LayerControls.

- You can set the tiles to `None` to not add automatically the baseLayer when using `folium.Map`

> tiles: str, default 'OpenStreetMap'
> Map tileset to use. Can choose from a list of built-in tiles,
> pass a custom URL or pass `None` to create a map without tiles.

- Now, you can add yourself the `folium.TileLayer` for darkmatter to display the background layer but saying you do not want to display it in the control.

To get transparent layer, we used the `opacity` option in `folium.TileLayer` (1 = fully opaque, 0 fully transparent)

A full sample available below can be used to "do the job"

```
import json
import folium
import requests


url = (
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/examples/data"
)
antarctic_ice_edge = f"{url}/antarctic_ice_edge.json"
antarctic_ice_shelf_topo = f"{url}/antarctic_ice_shelf_topo.json"

folium.folium._default_css.append(('leaflet_overloaded_css', 'https://your_url/your_css_file.css'))

m = folium.Map(
    location=[-59.1759, -11.6016],
    tiles=None,
    zoom_start=2,
)

tile_layer = folium.TileLayer(
    tiles="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    attr='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
    max_zoom=19,
    name='darkmatter',
    control=False,
    opacity=0.7
)
tile_layer.add_to(m)

folium.GeoJson(antarctic_ice_edge, name="geojson").add_to(m)

folium.TopoJson( 
    json.loads(requests.get(antarctic_ice_shelf_topo).text), 
    "objects.antarctic_ice_shelf", 
    name="topojson", 
).add_to(m) 

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m.save('/tmp/demo.html')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I meant transparency of the LayerControl panel, not the layer itself, but this is extremely helpful. I also want to customise the LayerControl icon and other things, would you suggest I dig through the Folium documentation or just use Leaflet directly?

Comment: Would use Leaflet directly except if you need to automate 20 maps creation and so manual creation is not worth the effort. Added `folium.folium._default_css.append(('leaflet_overloaded_css', 'https://your_url/your_css_file.css'))` if you want to overload default style like the control transparency