# Customizing layer control with CSS classes in Folium Leaflet?

Tags: python, leaflet, folium, streamlit

I am working with creating a folium map within [streamlit](https://streamlit.io/). I like the ControlLayer() functionality that folium provides, but I would like to be able to customize it a bit more. I found this [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402190/how-to-fully-customise-layercontrol-in-folium#comment656402_402201) that suggests appending css-classes to the folium default css list. I've tried overriding the classes that would effect the background color and label color, yet when I load the map, the default is still applied.

Would someone be able to explain what I am doing wrong? Could you please use my example to illustrate the correct way?

**map_test.py**

```
import folium
import pandas
import requests
from streamlit_folium import folium_static

state_geo = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium-example-data/main/us_states.json").json()
state_data = pandas.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium-example-data/main/us_unemployment_oct_2012.csv")

css_file = r"C:\Users\myname\leaflet_control_layer.css"

css_classes = [
    ('leaflet-control-layers', css_file),
    ('leaflet-control-layers-label', css_file)
]

# Append each class to Folium's default CSS
for label, css_file in css_classes:
    folium.folium._default_css.append((label, css_file))

m = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=state_geo,
    name="choropleth",
    data=state_data,
    columns=["State", "Unemployment"],
    key_on="feature.id",
    fill_color="YlGn",
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name="Unemployment Rate (%)",
).add_to(m)

# Add layer control
folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(m)

folium_static(m, width=800, height=800)
```

**leaflet_control_layer.css**

```
/* Change the background color of the control layer */
.leaflet-control-layers {
    background-color: #4b00ad; /* Change this to your desired color */
}

/* Change the text color of the control layer */
.leaflet-control-layers-label {
    color: #c70a9e; /* Change this to your desired color */
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizing ChatGPT, I learned that "For a Folium map that you intend to display within a Jupyter notebook or a web application, the CSS file needs to be accessible via a web address. This is because the Folium map is essentially a web page embedded within the notebook or web app, and it can only access resources that are available through HTTP or HTTPS protocols".

Given this, I used [Github pages](https://medium.com/flycode/how-to-deploy-a-static-website-for-free-using-github-pages-8eddc194853b) to host my css (pages needs a pro account fyi). I uploaded my file and updated my css_file location to `css_file_url = "https://quantumspatialinc.github.io/my-repo-name/leaflet_control_layer.css".

As TomazicM pointed out, I also was using the wrong css component.

```
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded {
    background-color: #4b00ad;
    color: #0ac733; /* Change this to your desired color */
}`
```

[image]

Comment: I admit I completely overlooked that you are trying to load CSS from local file. This is not allowed in web apps for security reasons.

Comment: Not a problem. First time really utilizing folium so I'm not aware of all the rules.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting CSS of the wrong component, it should be `.leaflet-control-layers-expanded`.

So this style:

```css
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded {
  background-color: #ff0;
  color: #f00;
}
```

gives this result:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I think it's due to that I am using streamlit. However I did find the solution. I'll post in a moment.

Comment: And yes, I was using the wrong component. Thank you for pointing that out. I noticed there are three different components (control-layers, control-layers-expanded, and control-layers-label). How do you know that expanded was the one? Why would labels not be?

Comment: I used browse debugger elements inspector, which is standard method in such cases. I haven't noticed `control-layers-label` style being used anywhere